# How to change the following printer properties, SpoolEnabled & KeepPrintedJobs, using C#?

Tags: c#, printing

I'm trying to change the printer properties, `SpoolEnabled` & `KeepPrintedJobs`, using C#. I tried using the `win32_printer` but the `SpoolEnabled` value didn't change. I'm using .NET windows forms (4.6) & Windows 10.

```
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer Where Default = True");
ManagementObjectCollection printerCollection = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query).Get();
if (printerCollection.Count > 0)
{
            foreach (ManagementObject printer in printerCollection)
            {
                PropertyDataCollection printerProperties = printer.Properties;
                if ((bool)printerProperties["Default"].Value)
                {
                    printerProperties["SpoolEnabled"].Value = true;
                    printer.Put();

                }
            }
}
```

Also, I tried using the following code with no success:

```
    ManagementPath mPath = new ManagementPath("//./root/cimv2");                           
    mPath.RelativePath = "Win32_Printer.DeviceID=\"" + PrinterName + "\"";
    ManagementObject Printer = new ManagementObject(mPath);
    string oldname = Printer.Properties["SpoolEnabled"].Value.ToString();
    Printer.Properties["SpoolEnabled"].Value = true;
    Printer.Put();
```

What library should I use, using c#, to change the SpoolEnabled & KeepPrintedJobs properties?

Comment: Hello Issam, welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you take a look at the System.Printing namespace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing?view=netframework-4.6.2

Comment: Hi Dabblernl, I can't find how to set those properties, SpoolEnabled & KeepPrintedJobs, under the namespace? I can get the KeepPrintedJobs value under the PrintQueue but there is no way to set the value.